# Adding node_modules to the content in React tailwind.config results in an error

Tags: tailwind-css

I am working on a React project composed of CRA.

An error occurred when I matched the tailwind settings and added the relevant settings to tailwind.config to use the local library with tailwind.

```
//tailwind.config.js

module.exports = {
    content: [
        "./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
        "./src/components/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
        "./node_modules/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"
    ],
```

The errors are as follows
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5Eg1.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your `node_modules` path might be too broad and covering more than you intend. This could lead to errors as you provided. Consider changing the `node_modules` to be more specific to the library you are consuming, like `./node_modules/my-library/**/*.js`.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue with `yarn pnp`.
My project was built on Next.js, NextUI and TailwindCSS.
The styles of NextUI components weren't appliy.
In my case I was looking for a specific `node_modules/package` in `tailwind.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './src/pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './src/components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './src/app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './node_modules/@nextui-org/theme/dist/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
  ],
...
}
```

So, the solution that worked for me was to add `nodeLinker: "node-modules"` into `.yarn.yml` and run `yarn install`